# React Checkbox is unchecked when there is a search input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, use-effect

I made a selectable and searchable popup list.

After I searched and selected names like the screenshot below

[image]

and open the popup again, searched with the same word or words contained in the selected usernames. The checkbox were uncheck and selectable, thus leading to duplicates.

[image]

**If I erase the word from search bar, the check box are checked.

[image]

Is there any way I can fix so that the selected will always remain selected?

Appreciate all your helps.

**UserList.tsx**

```
export const UserList = (props: {
    showsUserList: boolean; handleClose: () => void; corporationId: string; currentUserId: string; samePerson: boolean; twj: string;
  }) => {
    const handleOnMemberClicked = (checked: boolean, userId: string | null) => {
    const newList = addedUserList;
    const index = userList.findIndex((user) => user.userId == userId);

    if (checked) {
      newList.push({ userId: userList[index].userId, name: userList[index].name });
      setCount(count + 1);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
        if (newList[i].userId == userId) {
          newList.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
      setCount(count - 1);
    }
    setAddedUserList(newList);
  };
  useUserList(corporationId, props.twj)
  useAddUserList(addedUserList);
  const searchUserOnClick = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setUserName(e.target.value);
  };

  const searchedUserList = useMemo(() => {
    if (!userList) {
      return [];
    }
    let filteredUserList = userList
      .filter((user) => user.userId)
      .filter(({ userId, name }) => ({
        userId,
        name,
      }));
    if (props.isThePerson) {
      filteredUserList = filteredUserList.filter((user) => user.userId !== props.currentUserId);
    }

    if (addedUserList) {
      filteredUserList = filteredUserList.filter(
        (user) => !addedUserList.some((addedIds) => user.userId === addedIds.userId),
      );
    }

    return filteredUserList;
  }, [userList]);
    ......
    return ( <
      > <div className="reservation-popup-details scrollable">
            <ul className={`option-module-list no-list option-module-list-member ${style.personListMember}`}>
              {searchedUserList.map((user, i) => (
                <UserListElement user={user} handleOnMemberClicked={handleOnMemberClicked} isReset={isReset} key={i} />
              ))}
            </ul>
      .....
      </div>
    }
```

**UserListElement.tsx**

```
export const UserListElement = ({ user, handleOnMemberClicked, isReset,
}: { user: UserEntity;
  handleOnMemberClicked: (checked: boolean, userId: string | null) => void;
  isReset: boolean;
}) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const addedUserIds = addedUserList.map((item) => item.userId) || [];
  const handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const checkedState = e.target.checked;
    setChecked(checkedState);
    handleOnMemberClicked(checkedState, user.userId);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(false);
  }, [isReset, user]);
  return (
    <li>
      <label className={style.checkboxLabel}>
        <input type="checkbox" className={style.checkboxCircle} 
           checked={checked || isCheck} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)} />
        <span>{user.name}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  );
};
```

**UseAddUserList.tsx**

```
export class UserDetail {
  constructor(public userId: string | null, public name: string | null) {}
}

export let addedUserList: UserDetail[] = [];
export let setAddedUserList: Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserDetail[]>>;

export const useAddUserList = (idList: UserDetail[]) => {
  [addedUserList, setAddedUserList] = useState(idList);
};
```

**useUserList.ts**

```
export const useUserList = (corporationId: string, jwt: string) => {
  [selectedUserName, setSelectedUserName] = useState(ALL_USERS);
  [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  [userList, setUserList] = useState(INITIAL_USER_LIST);
  useAsync(
    async () =>
      setUserList([
        ...INITIAL_USER_LIST,
        ...(decideToGoToErrorPage(
          await CustomerListApi.search({ corporationId, userName, currentPageNo, displayCount }, jwt),
        )[1]?.map((user) => new UserEntity(user.userId ?? '', user.name ?? '', user.post ?? '')) ?? []),
      ]),
    [userName],
  );
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what `addedUserList` is in `UserList` but from what I can tell it's being mutated in the `handleOnMemberClicked` callback. This seems a bit of a code dump and you don't know specifically what/where the issue is and you want us to debug the entire thing. Have you done any debugging of your own yet? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was 2am in my local time so I was in a hurried and overlooked many infos that I should've added. And as you mentioned, running a codesandbox would be ideal, but this repository is a private one (company's) so I couldn't import it. I was able to fix it by making the user's checked property the same with addedUserList. However in the process, reset doesn't work on the radio buttons because I removed {checked }. I will be organizing things more nicely this time on a new post.

Comment: Ok.... a codesandbox doesn't need to be your private repo code, but a reasonable facsimile that reproduces the issue. The idea being if we resolve the issue there you can take the solution and apply it against your real code. You can just update this question if you like. If you do post a new question feel free to ping me here with a link to the new one and I can take another look. Cheers.